# content is the focus or in the focus

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, verbs, expressions

If I want to say that disturbing icons have been removed from my webpage and from now on, the content is emphasized, should I use the "content is the focus" OR the "content is in the focus" term?

Comment: [Relevant usage chart.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+the+focus%2Cis+in+the+focus&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) Unless they actually ***are*** "the focus", things are usually ***in focus*** or ***out of focus*** without any article.

Comment: this is good, thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

You should use "content is the focus". There is a difference between things being "the subject of focus" and what is being focused on (for example, with a camera lens).